# Object-fit:cover no longer working on tablecells?

Tags: css

My site uses square tablecells to show product images. Previously object-fit:cover worked fine but this no longer seems to be working on Chrome? The width of the image is set to the width of the containing div but the height is set to the actual height of the image, resulting in a wack display where the object-fit is calculated on the image's own overflown dimensions instead of the container's dimensions.

I hope I've included all the relevant code - I inherited this code from the website designer, and I'm definitely not uber-proficient with CSS (I've been trying to teach myself to maintain my own website) so I'm sure I'm just overlooking something. https://www.charmingsushi.co.uk/collections/all shows the error in action - images are 480px high, and are 'covering' that 480px instead of the shorter container.

HTML (a shopify liquid forloop iterates over each product on the page):

```
<div class="module-table">
 <ul class="grid clearfix collection-grid module-three-quarters">
  <li class="three-per-row centered prod-container">
   <div class="prod-image-wrap">  
    <a href="https://www.charmingsushi.co.uk/products/my-hero-academia-mochimochi-mascots">
     <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0988/2550/products/0017227_boku-no-hero-academia-mochi-mochi-tsum-mascot-individuals_x480.jpeg?v=1551836121"/>
    </a>
   </div>
  </li>
  <li class="three-per-row centered prod-container">
   <div class="prod-image-wrap">  
    <a href="https://www.charmingsushi.co.uk/products/riza-hawkeye-nendoroid">
     <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0988/2550/products/good-smile-company-riza-hawkeye-nendoroid-4858138296383_x480.jpg?v=1550853867"/>
    </a>
   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
$gutter: 8px;

.module-table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ''; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }

.row { @extend .clearfix; }

.row {
  margin-left: -$gutter;
  margin-right: -$gutter;
  margin-bottom: $gutter;
  clear: both;
} 

.column {
  float: left;
  padding-left: $gutter;
  padding-right: $gutter;
  padding-bottom: $gutter;
}

.grid { 
  @extend .row; 
}

.grid > li {
  @extend .column;
}

.collection-grid {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.module-three-quarters {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 75%;
  padding-left: $gutter;
}

.column.third { width: 33.3%; }

.three-per-row {
  @extend .column.third;
}

.centered { text-align: center; }

.prod-container {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.prod-container:before {
  content:"";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.prod-image-wrap {
    background: rgba(white, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: $gutter 0 0 $gutter;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.prod-image-wrap img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Can you replace the template values (like `{{product.url}}`) with example values? This will help people reproduce your problem. Thanks!

Comment: @araraonline I've done this now - couldn't find any sort of style guide for creating generic examples so I've just changed it to the first pair of actual values from the example page, hope that's better? Thanks for the tip!

Comment: That's better! Now, I think the code is way big to go through. Here's the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you've been searching for. I think I won't be able to answer you because of time, but, good luck!

Comment: @araraonline Ah, part of why I included all the code that's used to generate the problem div is that I don't know which part is causing the problem - I guess that means I should try and rewrite it from the ground up, but... fingies crossed that someone can point to the problem before I get hours in to redoing it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Fixed it myself like a tit - using https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/ which included the code:

    `.aspect-ratio-box-inside {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }`

My code was missing the position: absolute and top/left: 0 lines in the .product-image-wrap .img code. I still don't know why it was working and then stopped working, but oh well it's fixed and I got practice writing stackoverflow questions?

Comment: Really glad you got it working by yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself like a tit - using css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes which included the code:

```
.aspect-ratio-box-inside 
{ position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
}
```

My code was missing the position: absolute and top/left: 0 lines in the .product-image-wrap .img code. I still don't know why it was working and then stopped working, but oh well it's fixed and I got practice writing stackoverflow questions?